# Visual Studio 2022 Preview 3: Does not highlight missing reference

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2022

Just started experimenting with VS2022 Preview 3.
I just noticed that it does not show/highlight any missing references.
We have no clue about the missing references until you build the project.

Please see the attached screenshot.
[image]

Does anyone have any idea about this issue or have any remedy?
Am I missing any configurations?

Appreciate your feedback in this regard.

Comment: delete obj/bin folder, this happens since VS2017 and the SDK style projects

Comment: @magicandre1981, Thanks for the feedback. I just deleted the obj/bin folders. But I'm not sure about the SDK Style project. Can you please elaborate more on SDK Style project? - thanks

Comment: this is a [new csproj format](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/project-sdk/overview) with less entries.

Comment: @magicandre1981, Thanks for your feedback. I did try deleting the obj and bin folders but couldn't get the VS working as expected.